# Item selected by default in Android FloatingActionButton SpeedDial

Tags: java, android, android-layout, floating-action-button

I'm using [Leindardi FloatingActionButtonSpeedDial](https://github.com/leinardi/FloatingActionButtonSpeedDial) library to build an implementation of [Material design Floating Action Button Speed Dial](https://material.io/components/buttons-floating-action-button).

As suggested I've added the dependencies entry like this

```
implementation "com.leinardi.android:speed-dial:3.2.0"
```

This is where I add the **SpeedDialView** to my layout

```
<com.leinardi.android.speeddial.SpeedDialView
    android:id="@+id/speedDial"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    app:sdMainFabClosedSrc="@drawable/ic_add_black_24" />
```

This is my **onCreate()** method where I add the items to the SpeedDial

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ActivityMainBinding binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar);

    // Add camera action to SpeedDial
    binding.speedDial.addActionItem(
            new SpeedDialActionItem.Builder(R.id.fab_camera, R.drawable.ic_photo_camera_24)
                    .setFabBackgroundColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.white, getTheme()))
                    .setFabImageTintColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.black, getTheme()))
                    .setLabel(getString(R.string.camera_action))
                    .setLabelColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.black))
                    .setLabelBackgroundColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.white, getTheme()))
                    .setLabelClickable(false)
                    .create());

    // Add pdf action to SpeedDial
    binding.speedDial.addActionItem(
            new SpeedDialActionItem.Builder(R.id.fab_pdf, R.drawable.ic_picture_as_pdf_24)
                    .setFabBackgroundColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.white, getTheme()))
                    .setFabImageTintColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.black, getTheme()))
                    .setLabel(getString(R.string.pdf_action))
                    .setLabelColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.black))
                    .setLabelBackgroundColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.white, getTheme()))
                    .setLabelClickable(false)
                    .create());

    binding.speedDial.setOnActionSelectedListener(actionItem -> {
        if (actionItem.getId() == R.id.fab_camera) {

            startCamera();
            binding.speedDial.close(); // To close the Speed Dial with animation
            return true; // false will close it without animation

        } else if (actionItem.getId() == R.id.fab_pdf) {

            importPdf();
            binding.speedDial.close(); // To close the Speed Dial with animation
            return true; // return false to close it without animation

        }
        return false;
    });
```

The problem is that when I click on the FAB to espand it, the first item is "selected", the background is grey like when I touch it.
If I click anywhere else in the screen I can "deselect" it and the background becomes white again.

[Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yxKq2EY08GomIwQegPockP6Lli6s5TSK/view?usp=sharing) to a gif that shows the problem.

Any idea on how to solve this?